Help with proof for number of buffers in multiple frequency software scheduling
Suppose I have a software scheduler that creates a periodic schedule for processes $P_1,...,P_n$ of multiple frequencies $f_{P1},...,f_{Pn}$. The tick frequency $f_t$ of the schedule will be $LCM(f_{P1},...,f_{Pn})$ and the length of one full period $T$ will be $\frac{f_t}{GCF(f_{P1},...,f_{Pn})}$ ticks.
For example if we have processes $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$ with frequencies $f_{P1}=60$, $f_{P2}=100$ and $f_{P3}=200$ we end up with a tick frequency $f_t=LCM(60,100,200)=600$ and a period length $T=\frac{600}{GCF(60,100,200)}=30$ ticks, resulting in a schedule that looks graphically like this:
Schedule
Now suppose that the processes are exchanging data using a multi-buffered approach such that each process writes to an output buffer in every iteration, and every process will also in each iteration read all the buffers that it hasn't read yet from all the other processes. For example, the 3rd iteration of $P_1$ will read the output buffers from the iterations marked in this image:
Buffers read
Buffers read
The output from $P_2$'s 1st iteration was ready before $P_1$ started its 2nd iteration and has therefore already been consumed during $P_1$'s 2nd iteration. The output buffers from $P_2$'s 2nd and 3rd iterations are the ones that shall be read. By doing this for all three iterations of $P_1$ we can see that $P_2$ will need 2 output buffers.
However, $P_2$ must also be able to continue executing and write new output while $P_1$ is executing and consuming previous buffers. By also highlighting the iterations of $P_2$ that must be able to write to output buffers while $P_1$'s 2nd iteration is executing we get this result:
Buffers read and written
This shows that while $P_1$ is executing its 3rd iteration and consuming the output buffers written in $P_2$'s 2nd and 3rd iterations, $P_2$ will also need to write to output buffers in its 4th and 5th iterations. By doing the same thing for all of $P_1$'s iterations we will see that $P_2$ need 4 output buffers to never start overwriting buffers that $P_1$ is currently reading. If we perform the same exercise for $P_3$ we will see that it requires at least 8 output buffers (putting the lowest frequency process as the reader will always yield the worst case).
Basically I want to be able to calculate the number of output buffers needed for $P_x$ given an arbitrary number of processes and process frequencies involved.
I have used trial and error and reason to convince myself that the number of buffers needed will be covered (and sometimes exaggerated) by using the formula $\lceil\frac{f_{Px}}{min(f_{P1},...,f_{Pn})}+1\rceil$. Basically (my_frequency / lowest_frequency) + 1 rounded up.
Now to the questions:
Can I mathematically prove that this formula will be enough for all cases? If so, can someone please explain how? Or can someone come up with a better formula? For $P_2$ in this example this formula results in one more buffer than is actually needed. Not a big deal.
I know the exact answer can be found pretty easily using a software algorithm that does the same kind of manual counting of iterations that I used to illustrate the problem in the beginning of this post, but it would be nice to be able to use a simple formula instead.
